# Asp.Net Mvc Method OutputCache attribute set based on HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set a method attribute based on a debug flag. I expected to have compile time issues with this. Perhaps somebody can think of a workaround that works similar to what this would do if it worked.

```
[OutputCache(
    NoStore = HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled, 
    Duration=(HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)?0:15
)]///TODO: REMOVE THIS Attribute AFTER TESTING!
public ActionResult RenderSomething(int somethingID)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not use preprocessed conditionals?

```
#if DEBUG
    [OutputCache(
        NoStore = HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled, 
        Duration = 0)]
#else
    [OutputCache(
        NoStore = HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled, 
        Duration = 15)]    
#endif
```

..?

EDIT: I have confirmed this will work for my test of using the `Serializable` attribute. Should work for what you're trying to achieve (not sure if it's the best solution though.. but it works!).